# Is there any way to use Version One API to fetch team room scorecard details?

Tags: java, api, rest, versionone, agile-project-management

How can I fetch the details given in the image like total story points, detail estimate, capacity hours, done hours by using version one API.

[Version one scoreboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV2ct.png)

I have tried using many assets type like "Story", "Timebox" but can't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the PrimaryWorkitem asset instead of story.  Below is a JSON query using the /query.v1 endpoint that can get a team's planned points for a sprint in case that helps.

```
{
  "from": "PrimaryWorkitem",
  "where": {
    "Team.Name": "Example Team Name",
    "Timebox.Name": "Example Timebox for sprint"
  },
  "asof": "Example date of day after sprint started",
  "select": [
    "Estimate"
  ]
}
```